# Aurelia Component does not share instance when utilized in other viewmodels

Tags: javascript, aurelia

Here's a gist to illustrate:
https://gist.run/?id=8d4f38a9111b6cc0f068973e0c9e9c68

I have created a simple component with view/viewmodel, and included that into the index.html document. I want this component to be able to be interacted with from any other viewmodel in the app. But, when I include and inject into a different viewmodel it seems to have a separate instance.

In the provided gist you can see that the view is not updated from the initial message.

I feel that I'm missing something fundamental in the way that this is handled in aurelia. Can someone recommend the right way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

Solution is to use the `@singleton` decorator.

https://gist.run/?id=28b7901ab31cdab666a5f8f3d18abe23